# Etiquette for answering your own question when comments have been posted

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, accepted-answer, etiquette

If I post a question that is correctly answered in a comment to the question (i.e. no answer is posted, so nothing can be accepted as the correct answer) what is the correct thing to do?

1. Submit a new comment, asking the user who posted a correct answer in a comment to post an answer so that it can be accepted and so that the user gets the credit he deserves.
2. Submit an answer yourself, credit the user that posted it originally and accept your own answer.
3. Other?

*This is assuming that you have waited a few days so that the user who posted the comment with a correct answer has had time to post an answer in addition to the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation I would first ask the commenter to write up their comment as a full answer so that I could accept and upvote it (I have done this in the past on one or two of my meta.SO questions).

If the user in question were to then indicate that they didn't wish to do so, or if a few days have passed without them posting the answer, I would write up the answer that was provided in the comments, attribute it to the user that posted them, and post the answer myself with the *community wiki* checkbox ticked.

Ticking community wiki means that you gain no reputation from any upvotes (and lose nothing for any downvotes), so won't be seen as reaping the benefit of somebody else's work/answer.